# Is There A Function To Return The Index Of A List Without A Condition?

Tags: r

As the title suggests, I would like a way to return the position of an argument in a vector, regardless of it's value.

I have a list, say

```
mylist=list(c(1,2,3), 2, 3)
```

And I would like the first element to be 1, the next to be 2, and the third to be three. The ultimate reason why is so I can use the rep function with the index.

For example:

```
lapply(mylist, function (x) rep(?, length(x))
```

Is the right idea, I just need to know the function (? in the code) that will give me the values I want to repeat. Desired output would be 1,1,1,2,3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seq_along` is what you are chasing I reckon, as it counts along the components of an object.

```
seq_along(mylist)
#[1] 1 2 3

rep(seq_along(mylist), lengths(mylist))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 3
```